# magento2 add script tag right after open body tag

Tags: magento2

I want to add script tag (google tag manager) right after opening body-tag. I added a referenceContainer to default.xml - but content of "afterbody.phtml" is allways printed AFTER header.container instead of before.

Thanks for help!
martin

```
    <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="afterbody" before="header.container" template="Magento_Theme::afterbody.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <container name="header.panel" label="Page Header Panel" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="panel header">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="skip_to_content" template="Magento_Theme::html/skip.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">contentarea</argument>
                    <argument name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Skip to Content</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="switch/languages.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
        <referenceBlock name="compare" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="columns">
        <container name="div.sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-main-1" before="main">
            <container name="sidebar.main" as="sidebar_main" label="Sidebar Main"/>
        </container>
        <container name="div.sidebar.additional" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-additional1" after="div.sidebar.main">
            <container name="sidebar.additional" as="sidebar_additional" label="Sidebar Additional"/>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />           <!--for Create Account Link-->
        <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />          <!--for WishList Link-->
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true" /> 
    </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should not be. Check your layouts for the **move** instructions and other 
**referenceContainer**.

```
<move element="after.body.start" destination="..." />
...
<move element="header.container" destination="..." />
...
<referenceContainer name="after.body.start" after/before="..." />
...
<referenceContainer name="header.container" after/before="..." />
```

Link to documentation is http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html

Comment: thanks. i found <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true"/> in themeoption layout xml. so i tried to make new name - content is now printed before body end?<referenceContainer name="before.body.start">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="before_body_start" before="page.wrapper" template="Magento_Theme::afterbody.phtml"/>
  </referenceContainer>

Comment: Hmm.. no :) The location of the block/container does not depend of its name. Line <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true"/> must to removed header.container from page. This block is printed now?

Comment: the header.container is not printed. my new container is printed on the wrong place - it should be right after opening body-tag, but is printed after page-wrapper <referenceContainer name="before.body.start"> <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="before_body_start" before="page.wrapper" template="Magento_Theme::afterbody.phtml"/> </referenceContainer>

Comment: Try this: `<referenceContainer name="root"><block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::afterbody.phtml" before="-" /></referenceContainer>` It works for me - block display right after opening body

Comment: thanks! 
 
Try this: <referenceContainer name="root"><block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::afterbody.phtml" before="-" /></referenceContainer> It works for me - block display right after opening body is working!!!!

Comment: I'm glad to help :)

Comment: @Evgeny Levinsky, do I need to create afterbody.phtml file to place the link to JavaScript library?

Comment: @matin, please tell me how did you accomplush, I am at the same task now

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `<referenceContainer name="root"><block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::afterbody.phtml" before="-" /></referenceContainer>` It works for me - block display right after opening body